# Maintain call properties when using a regression with purrr::map

Tags: r

Suppose you have a list that contains multiple dataframes. Suppose you would like to "loop" through each of these dataframes within a regression model using `purrr::map`. However, you would like to maintain the names of the call$object. In the case below, you would like `cars_output[[1]]$call$data` to return `mtcars` instead of `.`.

```
library(tidyverse)

## creating a list of dataframes
cars_list <- list(mtcars, mtcars)

## iterating over each data frame within the model
cars_output <- map(cars_list,~lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = .))

## desired output would be mtcars, not .
cars_output[[1]]$call$data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a named `list` instead of just only values and then loop over the `list` with `imap` and modify the `call$data` with the names i.e. `.y`

```
library(purrr)
cars_list <- dplyr::lst(mtcars, mtcars)
cars_output <- imap(cars_list,~{
        model <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = .x)
        model$call$data <- .y 
   model})
```

-checking

```
> cars_output[[1]]$call$data
[1] "mtcars"
```